# what does the syntax in function foo({ defaultValue = {} } = {}) mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I came across this function the other day

```
 function foo({ defaultValue = {} } = {}) {
...
}
```

I don't understand what the `{ defaultValue = {} } = {}` part exactly means. I understand that there is an object property destructing for `defaultValue`, and there is a default argument set to `{}` if there is no arguments passed to this function. However I am not sure about what the combination is doing. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: the `= {}` below lets you call the function without any parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that there is an object property destructing for `defaultValue`, and there is a default argument set to `{}` if there is no arguments passed to this function.

Yes, that's what

```
function foo({ defaultValue } = {}) {
```

would be doing. The additional `= {}` in

```
function foo({ defaultValue = {} } = {}) {
//                          ^^^^
```

now provides a default value for the `defaultValue` variable, when the property does not exist in the object or is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice way of guaranteeing that `foo` will have access to the `defaultValue` property of the object argument passed in -

Given -

```js
function foo ({ bar = 1 } = {}) {
  console.log(bar)
}

foo() // => 1
foo({}) // => 1
foo({bar: 2}) // => 2
```

However watch out for `null` specifically -

```
foo(null) // => TypeError: cannot read property "bar" of null
```

If we skip the last `... =  {}` portion, then it will not be able to read `bar` in the `undefined` instance -

```js
function foo ({ bar = 1 }) {
  console.log(bar)
}

foo()
// TypeError: Cannot destructure property "bar" of undefined or null
```